# How do I create a dynamic quiz using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm looking into making a quiz where the user will be greeted with a "card" interface with both simple yes/no questions and some multiple choice questions. When answering one question, the next questions change to fit the previous answers.

Example flow:

Do you want to eat out or at home? I want to eat out. Do you want to eat at a Korean restaurant? Yes.

The problem I have is that I want this on the frontend without having multiple routes. Currently, I'm using Vue.js and Vue-Router. And this is what I have so for(don't mind the naming conventions, just temporary):

```
<template>

  <div>
    <div v-show="isQuestion(0)">
      <p id="question_1">Question 1</p>

      <p @click="answerQuestion()">Answer 1</p>
      <a @click="answerQuestion()">Answer 2</a>
    </div>

    <div v-show="isQuestion(1)">
      <p id="question_2">Question 2</p>

      <div v-show="isAnswer(0)">
        <p>Game?</p>
        <a @click="answerQuestion()">Yes</a>
        <a @click="nextAnswer()">No</a>
      </div>

      <div v-show="isAnswer(1)">
        <p>Read?</p>
        <a @click="answerQuestion()">Yes</a>
        <a @click="nextAnswer()">No</a>
      </div>

      <div v-show="isAnswer(2)">
        <p>Redo?</p>
        <a @click="resetAnswer()">Reset</a>
      </div>
      <a @click="search()">Search</a>
    </div>
  </div>

</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        question: 0,
        answer: 0,
        answers: {}
      }
    },
    methods: {
      answerQuestion () {
        this.answers[this.question] = this.answer
        this.question++
        this.answer = 0
      },
      nextAnswer () {
        this.answer++
      },
      resetAnswer () {
        this.answer = 0
      },
      isQuestion (n) {
        return n === this.question
      },
      isAnswer (n) {
        return n === this.answer
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

One option I'm thinking about would perhaps to put the questions with the answers in a database so that the frontend can fetch them as JSON and then populate the so called "cards". But then I have a problem with how to show the "correct" next question responding to the previous answers.

I don't feel comfortable hard coding everything as it seems like a bad practice but I'm having a hard time doing this any other way.

Comment: It helps, but I've still not fully tested everything. Will do so when I'm sure it fully works or if I can come up with a different solution.

Answer (score 2):

I think the point on your case is proper data structure. In your case I will use:

```
data () {
  return {
     curentQuesionIndex: 0,
     curentQuesion: null,
     questions: [
       { 
         question: 'Do you want to eat out or at home?', 
         options: [{0:'No'}, {1:'Yes'}, {'special':'reset'}], // answer options
         answer: 1                   // if NULL then user not yet give answer
                                   // if 'special' then you process it differently

       },
       ... // next questions here
     ]
   }
}
```

Using this array of questions you can render it in automatic way using Vue, (you can read it from ajax json), show next questions and other stuff. If answer in some question is NULL then you know that this is the 'next question' to show...

In your vue component create variable `curentQuesionIndex=2` and `currentQuestion= {..}` which you will use to show, save (into your query array), and operate (for instance of 'special' answer like 'reset').

You will use only one `@click` function: `saveAnswer(value)` where 'value' is the one option from `question.options`. Inside this funciotn you can save answer to questions list, set newq question to `currentQuestion` variable (which is rendered on screen) and depends of `value` you will make different actions - for instance: you will put if statement there: if questions[currentQuestionIndex].options[value] == 'reset' then you will reset...

Comment: Interesting, about the special cases, how would you go about processing it differently? Would you add an if statement inside the saveAnswer function?

Comment: I think `if` statements inside `saveAnswer` will be ok for this purpose. You can call other 'special' functions inside  `if` statements...